# Making policy in Laravel

Tags: c#, php, database, laravel

I have four tables

`user(username,role_id),
roles,
features(features_id,features_name),
feature_roles(pivot_table)`

user table has `role_id` and pivot table has columns (`feature_id`,`role_id`,`can_read`,`can_edit`,`can_delete` etc..).

I want to make policy according to user roles,to check which permission are assigned according to roles and features in a pivot table.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you show your user model?

Answer (score 0):

Define a policy for features named `FeaturePolicy` and register it in `AuthServiceProvider` like this:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Models\Feature' => 'App\Policies\FeaturePolicy',
];
```

Then in your controllers you can check the ability like this:

```
// $feature is some feature
$this->authorize('edit', $feature);
$this->authorize('delete', $feature);
$this->authorize('read', $feature);
// ...
```

Now is time to define the `edit`, `delete` and `read` methods in the `FeaturePolicy` class, for example for delete:

```
function delete(User $user, Feature $feature) {
    return $feature->roles()->where('id', $user->role_id)->wherePivot('can_delete', true)->exists();
}
```

You can implement other methods by just editing the query condition, you have to hard code them because there is no ability to use policies with parameters.

Comment: it is my Controller Code: public function listDepartment(Request $request,User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('read',$user);
        $department           = Department::with('role')->with('departmentName')->paginate($request->limit ? $request->limit : 50);
        if ($department) {
            return response()->jekoonApi($department, Power::LIST_DEPARTMENT, 'Department list details ');
        } else {
            return response()->jekoonApi(null, Power::LIST_DEPARTMENT, 'Department list details ', array('Department list doesnot exit'));
        }
    }

Comment: this action is unauthorized means the policy you wrote returned false and forbid this action

Comment: Can you give me a Example

Comment: i think the problem is with you database entry records. there is no problem with the logic and the code.

Comment: Suppose Department is a feature and in Database pivot table can_read column value=1 So according to your logic it should return true

Comment: check the query part by part. first log the `$feature->roles` and see if return all roles associated in the pivot table. then check `$feature->roles()->where('id', $user->role_id)->get()` return the specific role the user have. finally check if the `$feature->roles()->where('id', $user->role_id)->wherePivot('can_read', true)->exists()` returns true or what. check with the dd function